# Проблема сохранения данных из файла в базу данных MYSQL

Tags: файлы, кэширование, php, mysql

Добрый вечер. У меня  на сайте существую личные кабинеты. При авторизации пользователя система смотрит, есть ли у него кеш личного кабинета, если нет, то загружает из БД и загружает в кеш. Кеш построен на файлах, вида USER_ID.txt итак, все изменения, которые делает пользователь сохраняется именно в кеш. Далее крон каждые 10 минут, проверяет, есть ли файлы кеша пользователя, если есть, то перебирает и сохраняет данные в БД, далее очищает кеш. Все вроде бы норм, но порой возникает такая проблема, что информация не обновилась в БД, но файл кеша был стёрт, тем самым произошёл откат. Вот скрипт:

```
function Save($folder)
{
    global $Mysql;
    $GetFilesDir = Local_temp::GetFilesDir($folder);

    if($GetFilesDir == false){
        $Return['error']['get_files_dir'] = true;
        return $Return;
    }

    foreach($GetFilesDir as $key=>$file_name)
    {
        $Save = array();
        $Get = Local_temp::Get($folder.$file_name);
        if($Get == false) continue;

        $result = $Mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$Get['id']}' ");
        $myrow = $Mysql->get_array($result);

        if($myrow == false) continue;

        foreach($myrow as $k=>$v)
        {
            if(is_numeric($k)) continue;
            if($Get[$k] != $v) $Save += array($k=>$Get[$k]);
        }

        if($Save == false) continue;

        $UpdateUser = Update_user::Update($Save, $Get['id'], false);

        if(mysql_affected_rows() != 1) continue;

        $history_file_name = date('Y').'_'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'_'.date('H').'-'.date('i').'.txt';
        Local_temp::NewFolder('local_history_temp/users/'.$Get['id']);

        Local_temp::Set('local_history_temp/users/'.$Get['id'].'/'.$history_file_name, $Get);

        Local_temp::Drop($folder.$file_name);
    }

    return true;
}

/*
Local_temp::Get($folder.$file_name); - Получение файла кеша
$UpdateUser = Update_user::Update($Save, $Get['id'], false); - Обновление БД
local_history_temp - Директория отвечающая за архив кеша (так я и увидел, что систему откатывает)
Local_temp::Set('local_history_temp/users/'.$Get['id'].'/'.$history_file_name, $Get); - Новый кеш
Local_temp::Drop($folder.$file_name); - Удаление кеша

*/
```

Comment: Вы никогда не видели в интернете табличек типа "ни за что, никогда не сохраняйте постоянные данные в кэш, даже если вас об этом просит Гвинет Пэлтроу, наряженная Джейсоном Стэтхемом?"

Comment: Еще есть таблички "ни за что, никогда не выполняйте запросы к БД в цикле". Кроме редких исключений когда цикл маленький и статичной длинны

Answer (score 2):

1) Работа с БД безопаснее и структурирование, с БД работать наааамного проще, и работа вроде на чуть чуть медленнее чем с файлами, почему сразу в БД все не делать? Если учесть что идут ресурсы, на создание файлов, проверку файлов, удаление, -.-
2) По вашей проблеме, проблема с $GET - вы его не фильтруете (судя по коду), скорее всего он и вызывает ошибки.
3) Если все-таки фильтруете, то тогда поставьте контрольные точки (через 2-3 действия) и записывайте их в дебаг файл, когда встретится ваша проблема, вы сможете зайти в тот файл и проверить где что пошло не так.

Comment: Проект онлайн игры, база всегда нагружена, пришлось всё делать таким способом. Спасибо за помощь, попробую ваш метод